# Make look of Antd 3.x Tree to look like TreeTable

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I have some existing code that renders Antd 3.x [Tree](https://3x.ant.design/components/tree/). It uses lot of Tree props to manage the expand and collapse. Now I would like to show each Node(all nodes) separated by a line(to look similar to a Table) so all nodes are separated row wise. If I try to style "TreeNode", it obviously only applies to the node and since the arrangement of parent-child node is relative, it doesn't look like a table(row separated). please advice. TIA

Please see the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-night-fdju9?file=/index.css)

My last option would be to switch from Tree to [Table with Children](https://3x.ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-expand-children)